# How do i target an inline element and a block level element together?

Tags: html, css

I have a shortcode generated by a wordpress theme and the output is:

`<div class="heading clearfix"><i class="icon icon-list-ol h2"></i> <h2> Hello World! </h2></div>`

i need to style icon and h2 elements, How do i target them together?

tried this one:

`i.icon.icon-list-ol.h2  h2 {color:red;}`

but it didn't work.
PS: it's a shortcode generated by a wordpress theme.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Separate them with a comma:

```
i.icon.icon-list-ol.h2, h2 {color:red;}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. although do you recommend adding div. to be more specific as the below answer?

Comment: this depends on how yo're going to design your css in the whole. This is a very good reading if you want to know more about css specificity http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: Thanks for the invaluable resource, i mean if in case i used the same icon with h2 heading on another page of the site, i suppose the styles will also take effect on every same icon with h2 heading, would the below answer make it just for that elements?

Comment: if you only specify h2 (as I wrote in my answer), it will be global to all the h2 of your website. So, if you need to be more specific, you could use a more detailed selector, such as `div.heading h2`. Just experiment a little bit, and adapt your selector to the right specificity for you. I don't know how your website is designed :)

Comment: i couldn't mark the answer as resolved until 7 minutes i don't know why. anyways thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
div.heading i.icon,
div.heading h2 {
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: +1 for putting them both in the div, but I think using `heading` for the class is better. The `clearfix` is probably only a clear fix, not an identifier for the page section.

Comment: @MrLister Thanks ! Yes, you're probably right, I will edit my answer :)

Comment: so what should i use this or lorenzo.marocan one? what's the best for compatibility and specificity.

Comment: @Sup3r both are correct, use the one that you like the most. Don't forget to select a correct answer and up the answers that helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
i.icon.icon-list-ol.h2 + h2 {color:red;}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jzT2L/3/embedded/result/)**

Answer (score 0):

Won't

```
.icon , .h2 { color : red; }
```

work?

Comment: Anyway, to answer the question, no. This doesn't address the h2.

Answer (score 0):

Seperate **i.icon.icon-list-ol.h2 h2** with comma(,)

In **css** you have to change code as

```
i.icon.icon-list-ol.h2, h2 {color:red;}
```

Comment: Thanks, but plus(+) would only target the h2 element without the icon.